# Access to the path is denied in Vistual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio-code

I try to build a project but I got this error message,

```
Build FAILED.

/Users/ppungpong/Downloads/FPC_E_Working.API/FPC_EWorking.API.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [/Users/ppungpong/Downloads/FPC_E_Working.API/FPC_EWorking.API.sln]
/Users/ppungpong/Downloads/FPC_E_Working.API/FPC_EWorking.API.csproj : warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost 5.2.7' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project. [/Users/ppungpong/Downloads/FPC_E_Working.API/FPC_EWorking.API.sln]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.400/NuGet.targets(131,5): error : Access to the path '/Users/ppungpong/Downloads/FPC_E_Working.API/obj' is denied. [/Users/ppungpong/Downloads/FPC_E_Working.API/FPC_EWorking.API.sln]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/5.0.400/NuGet.targets(131,5): error :   Permission denied [/Users/ppungpong/Downloads/FPC_E_Working.API/FPC_EWorking.API.sln]
    2 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.05
➜  FPC_E_Working.API
```

The "**Access to the path ... is denied**" with "**Permission denied**"
How can I solve it?

Note: I use Visual Studio Code for Mac to run out my project and I use Mac M1 with BigSur 11.5.2

And I had allowed permission for file accessed.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create this directory :

```
/Users/ppungpong/projects/FPC_E_Working.API
```

and work in that directory.

Seems vscode does not have write access to Downloads folder.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurs when you try to install a `NuGet Package`.

[image: access-denied]

Follow the steps below to fix the problem:

1. Show hidden folders by clicking `Command + Shift + .`
2. Go to `/Users/{your-username}/.local/share`
3. Create the `NuGet` folder manually. Enter your password if needed.
4. Install the `NuGet Package`.

[image: the nuget path]

The package successfully installed.

[image: package installed]

Comment: This is the proper solution